# Joining 2 sql queries into one

Tags: mysql

I have an MySQL query of:

```
SELECT *, if (closeddate is null, 1, 2) as STATUS
FROM loanproc
```

I would like to be able to create the following two fields that would utilize all records to produce their resulting value for an overall statistic.

```
SELECT Avg((legalrecv - legalordered)) as avgLegal, Avg((appraisalrecv - appraisalordered)) as  AvgAppraise
FROM loanproc
```

Comment: Ok, what is the question?  Both your queries look syntactically correct (even if the second has extra parentheses).

Comment: some sample data and desired output you should provide...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
SELECT Avg((legalrecv - legalordered)) as avgLegal, Avg((appraisalrecv - appraisalordered)) as  AvgAppraise, Status
FROM 
  ( SELECT *, if (closeddate is null, 1, 2) as STATUS
    FROM loanproc ) T
Group by ...
```

Comment: That only retrieves one row of data.  I am needing to continue to see all records that the first query returns.  Sorry if I'm not explaining clearly enough.  I have a grid of data and I simply am looking to build 2 more fields to report avg days turnaround on two documents of which date request and date returned are gathered.

Comment: Thats 2 different queries: 1 for all the rows, and 1 for the fields. The alternative is returning the average for each row or the avg for the whole table in each row.